# VBS not Calling regedit object

Tags: vbscript, regedit

new to VBS, basically upon meeting criterias, the script will edit the registry, this is what i've got so far.

```
For Each ObjProcessor In ColSettings
If (ObjProcessor.AddressWidth = 64) Then
    If FSO.FileExists("C:\Program Files (x86)\A\A Client\B\SelfService.exe") Then
        strkey1 = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\A\B\C\STORE0")
        If (strkey1 = "AppGateway;https://A.net/C/B/Discovery;On;AppGateway") Then
            Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer &"\root\default:StdRegProv")
            strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\A\B\C\"
            strValueName = "STORE0"
            objRegistry.DeleteValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName
            Call MsgBox("Test: " & strKeyPath)
        End If
    End If
End If
Next
```

So, only the MsgBox function is working, the objRegistry.DeleteValue isnt. I've already declared objRegistry right before. Cant seem to figure out why

Comment: Make sure logged on user has permission to the registry keys.

Comment: d0h lol... cant believe i missed the most basic thing. appreciate that... however I havea  bigger issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logged on user should have permission to the registry keys. 
As per @Farhan comment, he got to know the reason. Putting in the answer as it will help other people who has similar questions.